# Find the probability that the fifth success in a series of Bernoulli trials will occur on seventh trial

Tags: probability

I need to find the probability that the fifth success in a series of Bernoulli trials will occur on seventh trial. How should I do that? Which formula should I use? It's not Bernoulli and not De Moivre–Laplace theorem, so what is it?

Comment: Hint:  in order for this to happen you need exactly $4$ successes in the first six trials, and you need trial seven to be a success.

Comment: Alternative Hint: a Negative Binomial distribution could help